# Looping through a webpage extracting several data from it

Tags: html, vba, excel

1 month ago, I asked a question on how to extract one value from a homepage, see
[Trying to extract ONE value from a webpage with VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594067/trying-to-extract-one-value-from-a-webpage-with-vba-in-excel)

I managed to get that to work, but then I realized that there is aloooooot of stocks out there, so after some thinking, I thought it would be better to try to make some kind of loop of a list-page instead. I found the page I was looking for
https://www.avanza.se/aktier/lista.html?countryCode=SE&marketPlaceOrList=MARKET_XSAT&sortField=NAME&sortOrder=ASCENDING&activeTab=quote

So after looking at the source-code of the homepage, I discovered that all the span classes has the same name (posting first two here)

```
<span class="se-14"></span>

<a href="/aktier/om-aktien.html/202888/203-web-group" class="link" title="203 Web Group">
        203 Web Group
    </a>

                        </td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort changePercent unknown">2.11</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort change unknown">1.30</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort buyPrice">120.00</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort sellPrice">118.00</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort lastPrice"><span class="pushBox roundCorners3">119.50</span></td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort highestPrice">122.00</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort lowestPrice">117.00</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort totalVolumeTraded">20000</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort updated">-</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort tools clearFix">

    <ul class="orderbook_tools cleanList floatList fLeft">

            <li>
                <a title="Lägg till kurslarm" class="icon alertIco triggerLogin" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a title="Visa anteckningar" class="icon noteIco triggerLogin" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a title="Lägg till i bevakningslistor" class="icon watchListIco triggerLogin" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
            </li>

    </ul>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="compareOrderbooks" value="202888"  />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="rowHighlight" data-oid="405356" data-delayed="true">
                        <td class="quote tLeft buySellButtons noSort">
    <ul class="cleanList floatList actionButtons buySellButtons">
        <li class="first">

                    <a href="/handla/aktier.html/kop/405356/a1m-pharma" title="Köp" class="orderLink XXSText">K</a>

        </li>
        <li class="last">

                    <a href="/handla/aktier.html/salj/405356/a1m-pharma" title="Sälj" class="orderLink XXSText">S</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</td>
                        <td class="quote tLeft instrumentName">

<span class="se-14"></span>

    <a href="/aktier/om-aktien.html/405356/a1m-pharma" class="link" title="A1M Pharma">
        A1M Pharma
    </a>

                        </td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort changePercent unknown">1.22</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort change unknown">1.11</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort buyPrice">50.00</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort sellPrice">48.00</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort lastPrice"><span class="pushBox roundCorners3">49.50</span></td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort highestPrice">50.50</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort lowestPrice">45.00</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort totalVolumeTraded">30000</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort updated">-</td>
                        <td class="quote tRight noSort tools clearFix">

    <ul class="orderbook_tools cleanList floatList fLeft">
```

As one can see, the span class has the same name (se-14).

So, what I would like to do!

1. First, extract the piece of information under title (first case 203 Web Group and put in cell An (for example A2)).
2. second, extract the last price of the stock (named LastPrice, for example 119.50 for the first stock) and put it in cell B2
3. go to the next stock, put it in A(n+1), for example put the name of the next company, A1m pharma in cell A3, and its latest price in cell B3, etc etc.

So question is, can one loop through the page, when all have the same span class name ?
And extract the whole list ? And put in the maner I would like, and can the cellname be a variable, like An, where n=n+1 for every loop the vba-script runs through ?

Since I'm quite new to Excel, please respond in a very basic language =)
Best Regards

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.  Your question **should include the code you are using and specific problem(s) you're having with that implementation**.  It should not just be a list of requirements.  There are at least **eight** questions in your question, which suggests you don't know anything and are simply looking for someone else to do your work.

Comment: @David Zemens - You are right (+1); why did I feel the desire to answer this?

Comment: Well, maybe I was a bit "lazy", but I really had no Idea where to start.

The code exist in the previous question asked (the top-link), but I was not sure how to get started with this next task.

Best Regards

Comment: You haven't shown any code so we don't know what method you will attempt. I suggest for others looking at this... take note.... provide an [MCVE] and perhaps look at getElementsByClassName method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody could write a regex expression for you.  Not me.
It's just a matter of programming:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sub1()
' assumes the html is in column C
' assumes roundCorners3 is a good pointer to lastprice
  Dim iposL&, iposR&, iLastRowC&, irowAB&, sCellC$, sTitle$, sLastPrice$
  irowAB = 2
  Do
    sCellC = getCellC()
    If sCellC = "EOD" Then Exit Do
    If InStr(1, sCellC, "<span class=""se-14"">") > 0 Then
      Do
        sCellC = getCellC()
        iposL = InStr(1, sCellC, "title=")
      Loop Until iposL > 0
      iposR = InStr(iposL, sCellC, ">")
      sTitle = Mid$(sCellC, iposL + 7, iposR - iposL - 7 - 1)
      Do
        sCellC = getCellC()
        iposL = InStr(1, sCellC, "roundCorners3")
      Loop Until iposL > 0
      sLastPrice = Val(Mid$(sCellC, iposL + 15))
      Cells(irowAB, 1) = sTitle
      Cells(irowAB, 2) = sLastPrice
      irowAB = irowAB + 1
    End If
  DoEvents
  Loop
End Sub

Function getCellC$()
  Static RowC&, RowCLast&
  If RowC = 0 Then RowCLast = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
  RowC = RowC + 1
  If RowC <= RowCLast Then
    getCellC = Cells(RowC, 3)
  Else
    getCellC = "EOD"
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Why assume the HTML is in the Excel file?  From previous Question, OP is automating Internet Explorer through VBA/Excel.  As such, the best solution is going to involve an XML/DOM parser, such as is available through the `Microsoft XML, v6.0` library reference :)

Comment: @David Zemens - Noted.