# Extract Value from a Webpage with VBA based on Tag

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

In need few help please in my VBA code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim IE As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ' You can uncomment Next line To see form results
    IE.Visible = False

    ' URL to get data from
    IE.Navigate "https://www.avanza.se/aktier/om-aktien.html/5247/investor-b"

    ' Statusbar
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading, Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Application.StatusBar = "Searching for value. Please wait..."

    Dim dd As String
    dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(" ")(0).innerText

    MsgBox dd

    ' Show IE
    IE.Visible = True

    ' Clean up
    Set IE = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

I want to extract a value  from a webpage which is in my case (computer 17) as mention the image by using VBA macro.

[image: Source code]

I already followed this link ([Trying to extract ONE value from a webpage with VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594067/trying-to-extract-one-value-from-a-webpage-with-vba-in-excel)) and it work but in my case I have multiple class inside each other.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something to get you started with the `InnerText` case:

```
Dim dd As Object
Set dd = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
Dim obj As Object
For Each obj In dd
    Debug.Print obj.innertext
Next
```

Write the code above on the place of `dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(" ")(0).innerText` and see the innertext of all `tr` on the site.

Comment: thank u so much,it work but i have another question please if the site need access like user and pass (sharepoint) can i still get any information from the website in case if am using this code?

Comment: @mictec - cool that it works. [What to do when someone answers a question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Concerning the second question, it is a good idea to ask it separately.